# How to update AzureWebJob after it is created

Tags: python, deployment, azure-webjobs-continuous

I created `AzureWebJob` manually via Azure portal, but now I need to update the source code. I did not found a way to re-upload the source code content (python script). Is there any CLI I can use to update the job or I have to delete the job and re-create it every time I need an update?

There is some guide to deployment via VS but only for .NET, is there something similar to Python?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final it is very easy!

It is possible to connect to App Service via FTPS client.

The credentials can be found in Azure Portal

`Home > <App Service Name> > Deployment Center > FTPS credentials`

And the source codes of the jobs are in the folder

`/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs`

and thats it!